# print int value from python nested dictionary, 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have tried to access a nested JSON file and print its data by import them to a python dictionary. When I print them out, there is an error at the last value which is an int value from the dictionary.

Here is my JSON data

```
{
"time": {
    "Thursday": {
        "21:00": 4,
        "1:00": 1,
        "4:00": 1,
        "2:00": 1,
        "20:00": 2,
        "22:00": 1,
        "19:00": 1,
        "15:00": 2,
        "13:00": 1,
        "23:00": 2
    },
    "Wednesday": {
        "11:00": 2,
        "13:00": 2,
        "14:00": 1,
        "17:00": 1,
        "6:00": 1,
        "2:00": 1,
        "0:00": 2,
        "1:00": 1,
        "21:00": 1,
        "18:00": 1,
        "19:00": 1,
        "20:00": 2
    },
    "Sunday": {
        "18:00": 1,
        "16:00": 1,
        "14:00": 1,
        "19:00": 2,
        "17:00": 1,
        "23:00": 1,
        "21:00": 1,
        "20:00": 5,
        "6:00": 1,
        "0:00": 1,
        "2:00": 2,
        "3:00": 3
    },
    "Friday": {
        "16:00": 1,
        "14:00": 2,
        "10:00": 2,
        "23:00": 1,
        "19:00": 2,
        "18:00": 1,
        "15:00": 1,
        "21:00": 2,
        "22:00": 2,
        "3:00": 1,
        "0:00": 2
    },
    "Saturday": {
        "21:00": 1,
        "23:00": 3,
        "18:00": 4,
        "10:00": 1,
        "12:00": 1,
        "13:00": 3,
        "14:00": 1,
        "15:00": 1,
        "16:00": 2,
        "17:00": 3,
        "2:00": 1,
        "0:00": 1,
        "1:00": 2
    },
    "Monday": {
        "12:00": 1,
        "11:00": 1,
        "14:00": 1,
        "18:00": 1,
        "19:00": 1,
        "23:00": 1,
        "20:00": 1
    },
    "Tuesday": {
        "18:00": 2,
        "12:00": 1,
        "13:00": 2,
        "16:00": 1,
        "15:00": 1,
        "4:00": 1,
        "21:00": 1,
        "20:00": 2,
        "23:00": 2
    }
},
"business_id": "7KPBkxAOEtb3QeIL9PEErg"
```

}

Here is my python code:

```
import json
with open('dataset/sample-checkin.json') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)

for day in d["time"]:
    for time in d["time"][day]:
        for checkin in d["time"][day][time]:
            print(day, time, checkin)
```

Error: for checkin in d["time"][day][time]: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That last loop doesn't make sense... there's nothing to loop over there. (The value is, as the error says, an `int`.) I think you probably want something like this:

```
for day in d["time"]:
    for time in d["time"][day]:
        checkin = d["time"][day][time]
        print(day, time, checkin)
```